# Manga where a male character gets disowned from his family then builds his own kingdom

Tags: story-identification, manga, evolution

I'm not sure but I know that he was disowned for having a weak "CREST" but then he gets shipped off to a deserted island. Then finds out that his crest was not trash but just that he has to be in a cave to unleash its potential. Then he mines and finds op ore. Then later a ship full of goblins or orcs but he befriends them and starts to builds his own kingdom.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like *[The King of Cave Will Live a Paradise Life](https://mangadex.org/title/49101/the-king-of-cave-will-live-a-paradise-life)*.

[image: Front cover of The King of Cave Will Live a Paradise Life]

> Hiel was ridiculed for having a useless crest and was exiled to a remote island. When he grabbed an pickaxe to reclaim the island, the true effect of his crest was revealed. With his production cheat he will reclaim this uninhabited island and start his life in paradise.

Found with a search for `manga crest mining`